# How to restore mongo db data from old files?

Tags: mongodb, express, ubuntu-18.04

my server crashed... I don't have a recent backup but I do have access of the files. I'm wondering If I can restore data from the old mongodb folder? any suggestions?

Comment: just copying the old files from /var/lib/mongodb worked but I had to fix the permissions

Answer (score -1):

You can get query logs mongodb.log file if your profiling level set  for logging any queries. If not, you can't restore.